# Как передать объект из динамически загружаемой DLL?

Tags: delphi, dll

Как передать ToolBar из динамически загружеамой DLL в Delphi?

Всем спасибо, кто ответил!

Comment: Посмотрите документ: [Dynamically loading a class from a dll](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20165).

Comment: @Бегемот интерфейсы стоит в ответ превратить, годная идея.

Answer (score 2):

По ссылке. Это простая часть, дальше надо тщательно следить, чтобы все соответствующие операции выделения/освобождения кучи происходили либо в приложении, либо в библиотеке. Либо юзать sharemem.